# Trim integer from a string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, trim

There is a `Trim` function that I can trim a specific character, but I was wondering if it could trim integers.

I have a list of strings:

```
'ABC01'
'ABCD02'
'AB5123'
```

Length and number are irregular.
After I run a SQL command, I would like to get this:

```
'ABC'
'ABCD'
'AB'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [translate function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions216.htm#i1501659). The REGEXP functions in Oracle tend to be CPU hogs compared to the simpler text processing functions.

```
select translate(string, 'A1234567890', 'A')
from t;
```

The "A" at the beginning of the second parameter, and matching A for the last parameter translates "A"s to "A"s, doing nothing, but without something in the third parameter string, ORACLE will return null.

**EDIT** *Simple test case*

```
SQL> create table t (string varchar2(100));
Table created.
SQL> insert into t values ('ABC01');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into t values ('ABCD02');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into t values ('AB5123');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into t values ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  2      || 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into t values ('123AB456');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into t values ('!Whatever!1');
1 row created.
SQL> commit;
Commit complete.

SQL> select translate(string, 'A1234567890', 'A')
  2  from t;

TRANSLATE(STRING,'A1234567890','A')
---------------------------------------------------
ABC
ABCD
AB
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
AB
!Whatever!

6 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(YourColumn, '[0-9]+', '') from YourTable
```

Take a look at this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8a83/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use function REGEX_REPLACE:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT regexp_replace( <<column name>>, '[[:digit:]]', null )
  FROM <<table name>>
```

will remove all the digits from the string.